# Collapse non-repeated columns into sublist c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have list of objects "orginalobject" is like below and also figure . This is populated from database

```
   orginalobject.monitorName
   orginalobject.ProcessGUID
   orginalobject.Apikey
   orginalobject.AIRSTATION
   orginalobject.variableName
   orginalobject.id
   orginalobject.AIRSTATIONChannel
```

As in Attached image you can see some columns are repeated that is

```
  monitorName
  ProcessGUID
  Apikey
  AIRSTATION
```

And non repeatable columns are

```
 variableName
 id
 AIRSTATIONChannel
```

so I want list should be grouped by these repeating columns and other columns should become list of this object using lamda or linq

```
object.monitorName
object.ProcessGUID
object.Apikey
object.AIRSTATION
Object.List<Subobjects> list
```

And Subobjects class will be like

```
    ObjectSubobjects.variableName
    ObjectSubobjects.id
    ObjectSubobjects.AIRSTATIONChannel
```

[image]

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you just want to group list of objects by their non-unique `monitorName`, `ProcessGUID`, `Apikey` and `AIRSTATION` properties used as a key and for each of these groups create list of sub-objects with the remaining unique properties?

This can be done with the following simple linq query. First it uses `GroupBy` to create groups of `originalobjects` with the same values of non-unique properties. I used `ValueTuple` struct to represent combination of non-unique properties as a single object used as a key for grouping. But from provided image it seems that it might be superfluous and that any of the non-unique properties alone used as a grouping key should be sufficient. The rest of the query contains just two projections (`Select`) that copies values from `originalobjects` to newly created `GroupObjects` and  `ObjectSubobjects`.

```
var groupedObjects = objects.GroupBy(o => (o.monitorName, o.ProcessGUID, o.Apikey, o.AIRSTATION))
    .Select(g => new GroupObject()
                {
                    monitorName = g.Key.monitorName,
                    ProcessGUID = g.Key.ProcessGUID,
                    Apikey = g.Key.Apikey,
                    AIRSTATION = g.Key.AIRSTATION,
                    list = g.Select(s => new ObjectSubobjects()
                                        {
                                            variableName = s.variableName,
                                            id = s.id,
                                            AIRSTATIONChannel = s.AIRSTATIONChannel
                                        })
                            .ToList()
                })
    .ToList();


public class orginalobject
{
    public string monitorName { get; set; }
    public Guid ProcessGUID { get; set; }
    public Guid Apikey { get; set; }
    public string AIRSTATION { get; set; }
    public string variableName { get; set; }
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public int AIRSTATIONChannel { get; set; }
}

public class GroupObject
{
    public string monitorName { get; set; }
    public Guid ProcessGUID { get; set; }
    public Guid Apikey { get; set; }
    public string AIRSTATION { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectSubobjects> list { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectSubobjects
{
    public string variableName { get; set; }
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public int AIRSTATIONChannel { get; set; }
}
```